# JSON API : Add a method called create_user to create a new user

Tags: plugin-json-api, wp-create-user

First of all I would like to thank **Dan Phiffer** for providing such a wonderful plugin.

I have installed the JSON API Plugin on my blog and it works and post perfectly.

The problem that I need to add a method called create_user to create a new user.

Can someone give me the steps to add such method to JSON API.

Thanks for all :)

Comment: Hi i believe this link will help u start..http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

Comment: thanks for your answer I found that link helpfull for someone how has such problem here is the answer http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#5.2.-Developing-JSON-API-controllers and the link that codebreaker posted

Comment: Have you checked out the one in development for core? https://github.com/rmccue/WP-API

Answer (score -1):

Please see this plugin and believe this is what you are looking for [JSON API User](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: True, I agree but I am new to php and wordpress, If someone can explain what is happening inside the code will help.